# Not able to connect to Android emulator via appium-RobotFramework

Tags: android-emulator, robotframework, appium-android

Want to run my native application via appium-robotframework. But appium is unable to connect to emulator

Installed appium windows installer, Ride, Nodejs. Installed “pip install robotframework-appiumlibrary”. added path to environment . Wrote a script in ride: 
*** Settings ***
Library           AppiumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Delivery
    [Tags]    run1
    Open Application    http://localhost:4723/wd/hub    platformName=Android    platformVersion=8.0.0    deviceName=emulator-5554    appPackage=com.android.Calculator    appActivity=com.android.Calculator
    Sleep    5s

Clicked run in Ride and started appium Node server

> Launching Appium server with command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --platform-name Android --platform-version 23 --automation-name Appium --log-no-color
>   info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.16 (REV ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d)
>   info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
>   info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"address":"127.0.0.1","logNoColors":true,"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"23","automationName":"Appium"}
>   info: Console LogLevel: debug
>   info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"appium:deviceName":"emulator-5554","appium:appActivity":"com.android.Calculator","platformName":"Android","appium:appPackage":"com.android.Calculator","appium:platformVersion":"8.0.0"}]},"desiredCapabilities":{"platformVersion":"8.0.0","deviceName":"emulator-5554","platformName":"Android","appActivity":"com.android.Calculator","appPackage":"com.android.Calculator"}}
>   info: Client User-Agent string: selenium/3.141.0 (python windows)
>   info: [debug] Didn't get app but did get Android package, will attempt to launch it on the device
>   info: [debug] Creating new appium session 76d74fa1-d43f-4060-b2a8-df3abbf9b60b
>   info: Starting android appium
>   info: [debug] Getting Java version
>   info: Java version is: 1.8.0_201
>   info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
>   info: [debug] Using adb from C:\Users\avishek.dhar\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   warn: No app capability, can't parse package/activity
>   info: [debug] Using fast reset? true
>   info: [debug] Preparing device for session
>   info: [debug] Not checking whether app is present since we are assuming it's already on the device
>   info: Retrieving device
>   info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\avishek.dhar\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
>   info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
>   info: Found device emulator-5554
>   info: [debug] Setting device id to emulator-5554
>   info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\avishek.dhar\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\avishek.dhar\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "echo 'ready'"
>   info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
>   info: [debug] Getting device API level
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\avishek.dhar\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>   info: [debug] Device is at API Level 26
>   info: Device API level is: 26
>   info: [debug] Extracting strings for language: default
>   info: [debug] Apk doesn't exist locally
>   info: [debug] Could not get strings, but it looks like we had an old strings file anyway, so ignoring
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\avishek.dhar\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "rm -rf /data/local/tmp/strings.json"
>   info: [debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
>   info: [debug] Skipping install since we launched with a package instead of an app path
>   info: [debug] Forwarding system:4724 to device:4724
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\avishek.dhar\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:4724 tcp:4724
>   info: [debug] Pushing appium bootstrap to device...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\avishek.dhar\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 push "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\android_bootstrap\AppiumBootstrap.jar" /data/local/tmp/
>   info: [debug] Pushing settings apk to device...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\avishek.dhar\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk"
>   info: [debug] Stopping logcat capture
>   info: [debug] Logcat terminated with code null, signal SIGTERM
>   info: [debug] Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...
>   warn: UiAutomator did not shut down fast enough, calling it gone
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
>   error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Command failed: C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "C:\Users\avishek.dhar\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk""
>   adb: failed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
>   info: [debug] Error: Command failed: C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "C:\Users\avishek.dhar\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk""
>   adb: failed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]
>
> ```
> at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
> at maybeClose (child_process.js:1016:16)
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1088:5)
> ```
>
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"C:\Users\avishek.dhar\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 install \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk\"\"\nadb: failed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]\r\n)","killed":false,"code":1,"signal":null,"cmd":"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"C:\Users\avishek.dhar\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 install \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk\"\"","origValue":"Command failed: C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"C:\Users\avishek.dhar\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 install \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk\"\"\nadb: failed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]\r\n"},"sessionId":null}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 8018.813 ms - 1418

expected was i should be able to launch calculator in android emulator to write further testscripts

Answer (score 0):

Your setup failed with:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]
```

Revise your setup, specially this:

```
info: [debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset info: [debug] Skipping install since we launched with a package instead of an app path
```